# Echo once in a foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a code in PHP. However when I `echo`, nothing is printed on page.

Can anyone help me?

```
public function checkcharacter(Request $request)
{
    $woord = str_split($request->session()->get('woord'));
    foreach ($woord as $letter) {
        if ($request->letter === $letter) {
           // return view('hangman')->getData (['goed', 'goed gedaan' =>$woord]); // =>$dottedword
            return view('hangman')->with (['woord' => $woord, 'correct' => 'fout']);
        }
        else {
            echo "wrong answer!";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly and you want to get only `wrong answer!` string once in the case if the latter isn't the same you need to use `break;` construction.

```
public function checkcharacter(Request $request)
{
    $woord = str_split($request->session()->get('woord'));
    foreach ($woord as $letter) {
        if ($request->letter !== $letter) {
            echo "wrong answer!";
            break;
        }

        // return view('hangman')->getData (['goed', 'goed gedaan' =>$woord]); // =>$dottedword
        return view('hangman')->with(['woord' => $woord, 'correct' => 'fout']);
    }
}
```

Hope I understand your question in the proper way.

**Upd 1.0**

If you don't want to break the loop, then I have the second way of resolving your problem:

```
public function checkcharacter(Request $request)
{
    $woord = str_split($request->session()->get('woord'));
    $isCorrect = true;

    foreach ($woord as $letter) {
        if ($request->letter !== $letter) {
            $isCorrect = false;
        }

        // return view('hangman')->getData (['goed', 'goed gedaan' =>$woord]); // =>$dottedword
        return view('hangman')->with(['woord' => $woord, 'correct' => 'fout']);
    }

    if (!$isCorrect) {
        echo 'wrong answer!';
    }
}
```

Comment: So won't this always finish when it has only checked the first letter of the word?

Comment: If the first latter doesn't require to the condition, then yes, this loop will finish right after first condition returns `true`. If you want to continue your loop anyway, you should use a bit different logic. Please check my upd 1.0

Answer (score 0):

The following else block should be outside of foreach block

```
else {
   echo "wrong answer!";
}
```

So suppose the if condition is success then the flow will return without any echo. I have not run this snippet. Please check it at your end.

```
public function checkcharacter(Request $request)
{
    $woord = str_split($request->session()->get('woord'));
    foreach ($woord as $letter) {

        if ($request->letter === $letter) {
           // return view('hangman')->getData (['goed', 'goed gedaan' =>$woord]); // =>$dottedword
            return view('hangman')->with (['woord' => $woord, 'correct' => 'fout']);
        }
    }
    // if answer is not found then will give the following echo once.
    echo "wrong answer!";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the letter is in the word, there is no need for a loop, just check if the letter is in the word - I use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
public function checkcharacter(Request $request)
{
    if ( strpos ($request->letter, $request->session()->get('woord')) !== false)   {
        return view('hangman')->with (['woord' => $woord, 'correct' => 'fout']);
    }
    else {
        return view('hangman')->with (['woord' => $woord, 'correct' => 'false']);        
    }

}
```

Note that both branches return a view - the second one where the letter isn't found sets `'correct' => 'false'` which you may need to change to suit your needs.